# How to convert the output of a neural network into probabilities?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am currently working on an image recognition problem where I would like to recognize images with the highest probability, meaning the expectation is to match an image having a maximum percentage of match score from the pool of images given input test images.

I want any ideas, suggestion or any blog post via which I can move forward with it.

1. I have written a CNN classifier that consists of usual convoluted, max pooled layers;
2. then I used Keras's ImageDataGenerator function to use image augmentation. I applied that to the training set and also set rescaled my test set as well.
3. Then I tested the algorithm with some random images. But I need some idea on how exactly I can match an image having a maximum percentage of match score from the pool of images given input test images.
4. At this moment I am just passing one image as input and the algorithm is returning whether it is a cat or a dog or any material.

Please let me know if the requirement is unclear I will provide all the nitty-gritty.

```
             classifier = Sequential()
             classifier.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape =(600,200,3), 
                                                     activation ='relu')) 
             classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

             classifier.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation ='relu')) 
             classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
             classifier.add(Flatten())
             classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation ='relu'))
             classifier.add(Dropout(0.4))
             classifier.add(Dense(units = 64, activation ='relu'))
             classifier.add(Dense(units = 3, activation ='softmax'))
             classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 
             'categorical_crossentropy', metrics =['accuracy'])  

             #Testing
              img_width, img_height = 600, 200

              def prediction(file):
                    x = load_img(file, target_size=(img_width,img_height))
                    x = img_to_array(x)
                    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
                    array = classifier.predict(x)
                    result = array[0]
                    #print(result)
                    answer = np.argmax(result)
                    if answer == 1:
                       print("Predicted: Dog")
                    elif answer == 0:
                       print("Predicted: Cat")
                    elif answer == 2:
                       print("Predicted: Materials")
```

I want the output like this, given an image, it should show me the probability of which of the category it belongs to, e.g. dog: 23%, cat: 2%, materials: 75%

Comment: Can you show us the code with which you add the last layers to your model?

Comment: classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation ='relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.1))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 64, activation ='relu')) #Hidden Layers
classifier.add(Dense(units = 3, activation ='softmax')) #Output Node
#Compiling
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics =['accuracy'])

Comment: Ok, looks right. Can you also add the code with which you are testing your model and getting the prediction for an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to use a sigmoid transfer function on the output layer nodes (that accepts data ranges (-inf,inf) and outputs a value in [-1,1]).
Then by using the 1-of-n output encoding (one node for each class), you can map the range [-1,1] to [0,1] and use it as probability for each class value (note that this works naturally for more than just two classes).

You can read more, including proofs of probabilistic interpretation here:

[1] Bishop, Christopher M. Neural networks for pattern recognition. Oxford university press, 1995.

**Simple example**

If you want's probabilities as output of the network you can use `softmax` after the `Dense` layer.

```
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# probability array
probabilities = model.predict(image)[0]

# get predicted classes
pred_classes = np.argmax(probabilities)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion! I understand in which perspective you are saying this but can you just share some more insight on this, I'm unable to visualize the code.

Comment: @user11409134 I have added a simple example on how you can get class probability with `Softmax` layer. Cheers